# I need help about client certificates nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a problem when I want to put 2 client certificates because 1 of them is going to expire and I don't want to stop the service.

I trie this:

ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert1.crt;

ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert2.crt;

ssl_verify_client on;